# How can I implement this code into this GUI effectively? (Im kind of new to coding) Just asking for a general idea or tips

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

The code I have in my orignal command line interface code is the following:

````
    ```import numpy, random, time, sys
import requests
from random import randint

url = 'https://svnweb.freebsd.org/csrg/share/dict/words?view=co&content-type=text/plain'

r = requests.get(url)
text = r.text
# print(text)
individual_words = text.split()
# print(individual_words)
a = ""
print("====Welcome to the Username Generator!====")
userKey = input("Please input your desired base word or base letter to base your username off of: ")
print("Your base word is:", userKey,
", is this what you want to continue with?")
maxlength = len(userKey)
userConfirm = input("Y/n: ")
maxlength = len(userKey)
random_number = randint(0,len(individual_words))
if userConfirm == "Y" or "y":
    nameOrder = []
    nameOrder.append(userKey)
    nameOrder.append(str(random_number))
    nameOrder.append((individual_words)[random_number])
    random.shuffle(nameOrder)
    print("".join(nameOrder))
else:
    print("invalid")
    sys.exit()
````

and My desired outcome is to somehow insert it to execute in my GUI interface, but right now im just focusing on being able to get it to print or repeat the user input that was written the 'entry' function on the GUI interface. I have tried to implement this but have failed, suggestions, comments, or small tips would help me greatly! The GUI code consists of the following (I attempted to implement my code in this version)

````
``` import tkinter as tk
    import numpy, random, time, sys
    import requests
    from random import randint

    H = 400
    W = 800
    def test_function(entry):
        print("This is the entry:", entry)
    a = ""

def format_response(name):
    try:
        name = weather['name']
        desc = weather['weather'][0]['description']
        temp = weather['main']['temp']

        final_str = 'nameOrder'
    except:
        final_str = 'There was an issue creating your username'

    return final_str

def get_username(entry):
    url = 'https://svnweb.freebsd.org/csrg/share/dict/words?view=co&content-type=text/plain'
    r = requests.get(url)
    text = r.text
    individual_words = text.split()
    print("====Welcome to the Username Generator!====")
    userKey = input("Please input your desired base word or base letter to base your username off of: ")
    print("Your base word is:", userKey,
    ", is this what you want to continue with?")
    maxlength = len(userKey)
    userConfirm = input("Y/n: ")
    maxlength = len(userKey)
    random_number = randint(0,len(individual_words))
    if userConfirm == "Y" or "y":
        nameOrder = []
        nameOrder.append(userKey)
        nameOrder.append(str(random_number))
        nameOrder.append((individual_words)[random_number])
        random.shuffle(nameOrder)
        print("".join(nameOrder))
    else:
        print("invalid")
        sys.exit()


root=tk.Tk()
#INFO KEY: the .pack at the bottom has brackets, in between () type whatever side you want it to be
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=H, width=W)
canvas.pack()

frame = tk.Frame(root, bg ='#dfbf9f', bd=5) #the frame is basically where to frame the bg color
frame.place(relx = 0.5, rely = 0.1, relwidth=0.75, relheight=0.1, anchor='n') #rel means relative, so relative width, etc

label = tk.Label(frame, text = "label testing", bg = '#004d00')
label.place()

entry = tk.Entry(frame, bg = 'gray',font=40)
entry.place(relwidth=0.65, relheight =1)

button = tk.Button(frame, text="Submit", bg ='green', font= 40, command=lambda: get_username(entry.get()))
button.place(relx=0.7, relheight=1, relwidth=0.3)

lower_frame= tk.Frame(root, bg='#dfbf9f', bd=9)
lower_frame.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.25, relwidth=0.75, relheight = 0.6, anchor='n')


root.mainloop()```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So im new to programming as well and im sure experienced people will find a prettier solution to this but i think i found a solution to your problem(more or less)

```
import tkinter as tk
import numpy, random, time, sys
import requests
from random import randint

H = 400
W = 800
class RandomUsername():
    def __init__(self, entry):
        self.name = ""
        self.entry = entry
    def create_username(self):
        self.name = get_username(self.entry)




def get_username(entry):
    url = 'https://svnweb.freebsd.org/csrg/share/dict/words?view=co&content- 
    type=text/plain'
    r = requests.get(url)
    text = r.text
    individual_words = text.split()
    userKey = entry
    maxlength = len(userKey)
    maxlength = len(userKey)
    random_number = randint(0,len(individual_words))
    nameOrder = []
    nameOrder.append(userKey)
    nameOrder.append(str(random_number))
    nameOrder.append((individual_words)[random_number])
    random.shuffle(nameOrder)
    final_name = "".join(nameOrder)
    return final_name

def callback(output_label):
    new_entry = entry.get()
    new_name = RandomUsername(new_entry)
    new_name.create_username()
    name_to_display = new_name.name
    output_label.config(text=name_to_display)



root=tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=H, width=W)
canvas.pack()

frame = tk.Frame(root, bg ='#dfbf9f', bd=5) 
frame.place(relx = 0.5, rely = 0.1, relwidth=0.75, relheight=0.1, anchor='n')

label = tk.Label(frame, text = "label testing", bg = '#004d00')
label.place()

entry = tk.Entry(frame, bg = 'gray',font=40)
entry.place(relwidth=0.65, relheight =1)

lower_frame= tk.Frame(root, bg='#dfbf9f', bd=9)
lower_frame.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.25, relwidth=0.75, relheight = 0.6, anchor='n')

name_to_display = ""
output_label = tk.Label(lower_frame, text=name_to_display, bg="#dfbf9f")
output_label.place(x=10, y=20)

button = tk.Button(frame, text="Submit", bg ='green', font= 40, command=lambda: 
callback(output_label))
button.place(relx=0.7, relheight=1, relwidth=0.3)



root.mainloop()
```

Explanation:
First of all, i removed all the print statements, since when using a gui they are not really needed anymore, but that is personal preference. 
Tkinter Buttoncallbacks dont really allow for a return, so to still get a value out of the function u can create a class, then save the output of the get_username function to the objcet. At last, the methond ".config" allows you to update the content of a label. Hope this helps and if a more experienced programmer could provide a better solution, im very interested.

Comment: Thanks! It was a success! Props to you man, I would totally upvote but I only have 1 rep haha.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused by what you're trying to do, please could you clarify?

The first bit of code you pasted looks like its from a python script? But you're saying it's in your command line interface?

When you say you're trying to get it to execute in the GUI interface, what exactly do you mean?

Are you trying to find a way to execute the code using your GUI?

Comment: Correct, it uses command line interface. When you execute it, it will run through the python CMD. When I say "execute it" I mean to simply be able to execute that batch of code with the press of the button I implemented into my GUI, which is labeled as so, and then have the output print into the GUI interface ( as an end goal).